# How to fix error "please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>" in Next 14 with redux tollkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-redux

I am having a very hard time making Next.js 14 working with Redux `Provider`. I follow all the instructions on the [Redux official doc here](https://redux.js.org/usage/nextjs) but I keep getting this error:

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the
> component is wrapped in a

[image]

And I cannot find a solution anywhere.
These are my structure and files:
--app
--StoreProvider.tsx
--page.tsx
--lib
--store.ts
--hooks.ts
--features
--counter
--counterSlice.ts
--Counter.tsx

StoreProivder.tsx

```
'use client'

import { useRef } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { makeStore, AppStore } from '../lib/store'

export default function StoreProvider({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>()
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore()
  }

  return <Provider store={storeRef.current}>{children}</Provider>
}
```

hooks.ts

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector, useStore } from 'react-redux'
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch, AppStore } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
export const useAppStore: () => AppStore = useStore
```

store.ts

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const makeStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {}
  })
}

// Infer the type of makeStore
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch']
```

Counter.tsx

```
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch, useAppStore  } from '../../hooks';
import {
  decrement,
  increment,
  incrementByAmount,
  selectCount,
} from './counterSlice';
import styles from './Counter.module.css';

export function Counter() {
  const count = useAppSelector(selectCount);

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [incrementAmount, setIncrementAmount] = useState('2');

  const incrementValue = Number(incrementAmount) || 0;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          aria-label="Decrement value"
          onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}
        >
          -
        </button>
        <span className={styles.value}>{count}</span>
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          aria-label="Increment value"
          onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <input
          className={styles.textbox}
          aria-label="Set increment amount"
          value={incrementAmount}
          onChange={(e) => setIncrementAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className={styles.button}
          onClick={() => dispatch(incrementByAmount(incrementValue))}
        >
          Add Amount
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

counterSlice.ts

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../../store';

export interface CounterState {
  value: number;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0,
  status: 'idle',
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },

});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;
export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.counter.value;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

page.tsx

```
import { Counter } from '../lib/features/counter/Counter'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Counter />
  )
}
```

The error is here: `const count = useAppSelector(selectCount)` in Counter.js, and it says I didn't wrap it in `Provider`, when I assume it is done in the StoreProvider.tsx, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see where did you actually use `<StoreProvider>` ?

Comment: From the docs: "The next step is to include the StoreProvider anywhere in the tree above where the store is used. You can locate the store in the layout component if all the routes using that layout need the store. Or if the store is only used in a specific route you can create and provide the store in that route handler." So you gotta use `StoreProvider` in `page.tsx` or in the respective layout component.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added this library?
`yarn add next-redux-wrapper` (learn more [here](https://yarnpkg.com/package?name=next-redux-wrapper&version=9.0.0-rc.2)).
If you are using npm instead of yarn use this command instead: `npm install next-redux-wrapper`
This library permit you to use the global state of redux in both environments client and server.

Other solution is to use redux features only in clients components by adding this syntaxe at the top of all components that make use of redux.
`"use client"` like that, the redux work will only be used on client environnement that is the suit environnement of simple redux.
Learn more about Next clients components [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)